# Riot LOL api static ddragon JSON

Tags: riot-games-api

I got a problem. In static LOL json I got a list of champions and everything about them. I would like to fill the {{ f[number] }} values. I have no idea how to do it, how to calculate this value or something.

You can see it there: http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/tool/, for example click Ahri and check spells -> 2nd spell.

> for a maximum of undefined damage to a single enemy.

They haven't fill it, but I think it is possible in some way, because I got whole information about champions.

This undefined is in JSON {{ f1 }}, the are other values like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm  guessing, but...

I think you'll find that the spell information is from the same data source as the in-game spell info tool tips. That ***undefined*** / ***{{f1}}*** place holder is replaced in-game by a formula based on the player's current *level* and or *ability power* or some other factor.

As this data is outside the context of the game, the need to replace this with a representation. I guess maybe they forgot to provide a scaling list of values for that particular formula, or it doesn't translate to a list like that so maybe they just left it.

It could potentially be a bug, and is worth reporting to Riot.